# How can I see what instruction my computer is executing?

Tags: networking, server

My computer becomes extremely slow and I see the hard disk accessing as if someone was taking backup. How can I see what instruction my computer is executing?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64-bit on an HP Intel i3 computer, 1.5 TB hard drive, 4 GB RAM.

Comment: Have you taken a look at `htop`?

Answer (score 0):

To see what processes are currently most CPU or memory demanding, you can use htop

`sudo apt-get install htop`

`sudo htop`

[image]